# C# Hangman game: not updating according to subsequent user guesses

Tags: c#

I've created a very simple hangman game, asking a user to input a letter as a guess. The first time that the user inputs a correct guess, the game records it, and the console displays the correct letters. However, with each subsequent correct guess, the array that I created for the solution apparently is not updated, and the console does not write the 2nd correct guess. Also, the user does not lose a life with each incorrect guess.

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hangman2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[]letters = {"a","e","r","o","p","l","a","n","e"};

        static int Lives = 7;
        static string Gu = ""; // this is not being updated with each guess 
        static string[]Solution = new string[letters.Length];

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FillSolution();
            UserGuess();

            while (Lives > 0) {
                UserGuess();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void FillSolution()
        {
            string star = "*";

            for(int i = 0; i < Solution.Length; i++) {
                Solution[i] = star;
            }
        }

        static void UserGuess() 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess");
            string Guess = Console.ReadLine();
            Gu += Guess; //this isn't working

            bool GuessRight = false;
            for(int i = 0; i<letters.Length; i++) {
                string y = letters[i];

                if(Gu == y) {
                    Solution[i] = letters[i];
                    GuessRight = true;
                }
                else {
                    GuessRight = false;
                }

                if(GuessRight = false) {
                    Lives--; // this is also not working
                }
            }
            DisplaySolution();
        }

        static void DisplaySolution()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < Solution.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write(Solution[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You have " + Lives + " lives remaining");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you become comfortable with the debugger.  You can step through the code and look at the value of each variable as you're doing so, which should help you determine what's going wrong.  I'm assuming you're using an IDE like VS with that capability of course.

Answer (score 4):

Your if statement is using the assignment operator rather than checking if it is equal to false

```
if(GuessRight = false){
```

should be

```
if(GuessRight == false){
```

or just

```
if(!GuessRight){
```

---

Also, the entire if statement for your current check is wrong, you need to find if the solution has the guess in it rather than string concatenating to your `Gu` string (which isn't needed)

```
var idx = Array.IndexOf(letters, Guess);
if(idx >= 0){
    while(idx >= 0){
        Solution[idx] = Guess;
        idx = Array.IndexOf(letters, Guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: they had `else { }`, you have `else ( )`, but that would have to be `else if ( )` to compile

Comment: The else does not contain a logical condition. They are actually trying to assign the value of GuessRight.
`else {
    GuessRight = false;
}`

Comment: @flamewave000 - Good spot, the formatting threw me off

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I noticed is in line 72, you wrote:

```
if (GuessRight = false)
```

The reason why this is problematic is because you are trying to set the value of GuessRight variable to false (which you had already done previously) whereas you are meant to be checking if `GuessRight` is equal to false with "`==`" which is the equality operator. The line should read:

```
if (GuessRight == false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should fix some of your life counting issue. I'm not sure why the string concatenation is not currently working for you.

```
static void UserGuess() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess");
    string Guess = Console.ReadLine();
    Gu += Guess; // this should work

    bool GuessRight = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<letters.Length; i++){
        string y = letters[i];
        if(Gu == y) {
            Solution[i] = letters[i];
            GuessRight = true;
        }
        else {
            GuessRight = false;
        }
        if(GuessRight == false) {// Have to use '==' when comparing, '=' will assign the value
            Lives--;
        }
    }
    DisplaySolution();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

also to @Sayse & Harry for pointing out the same 

Now, when I input a correct guess, I end up with (Lives = 0), and when I input an incorrect guess, I end up with (Lives = -2). So, an incorrect guess is causing the Lives to decrease by the number of elements in the array ...

Comment: You need to add a `break;` after `Lives--;`

Answer (score 0):

So, where I went wrong by having the first 'for' loop go down to line 78.
Thanks to everyone for all of your replies!

```
bool GuessRight = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<letters.Length; i++){
            if(Guess == letters[i]){ 
                Solution[i] = letters[i];
                GuessRight = true;

            }   
        } // this was the right place to close it, not after the 'Lives--'
        if(!GuessRight){
        Lives--;
        }
```